# Part of Decrypt non-sense

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am working a chat in android, here I am using the next methods for key generation, encrypt and decrypt messages. The problem is that when I send a message for example "hola" in the other side I get "holgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA". Could you help to fix this?.

```
private byte[] K;
public void setK(){
    KeyGenerator KeyGen=KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    KeyGen.init(128);
    SecretKey key=KeyGen.generateKey();
    K = key.getEncoded();
}
public String encrypt(byte[] input){
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.decode("Hola".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(K, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
        int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
        ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
        return Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(JUAN, "failed to encrypt ", e);
    }
    return null;
}

public String decrypt(byte[] input){
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.decode("Hola".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(K, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] plainText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
        int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, plainText, 0);
        ctLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, ctLength);
        return Base64.encodeToString(plainText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(JUAN, "failed to decrypt ", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is my calling, for example to encrypt "Hola".

```
encrypt(Base64.decode("Hola".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
decrypt(Base64.decode(ciphertext, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. The padding is removed successfully according to the OP's code. The OP made a mistake to output the Plaintext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK assuming that the parameter `input` in your `public String decrypt(byte[] input)` method is successfully Base64 decoded from the cipher text by the caller (because your encrption returns Base64 encoded cipher string). But, in the `decrypt()` method  you are creating a `byte` array `plainText` by [getOutputSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getOutputSize%28int%29) method. That makes `plainText` an array of size of multiple of AES Block Size(16). For your case, `plainText` is a `16 byte` array. So after decrypting and removing the paddings from cipher text the `plainText` contains the decrypted text with some zeroes, those zeroes are then encoded into `AAA...As`.
So use

```
return Base64.encodeToString(plainText, 0, ctLength, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

instead of

```
return Base64.encodeToString(plainText, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**Note:** You are using `ECB` mode, so your `IvParameterSpec` is useless. Use `CBC` mode instead.

**Edition:** Your calling is not OK. Try this

```
//Encryption side
String text = "hola, hi, anything u want";
byte[] plainText = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = encrypt(plainText);

// Decryption side
byte[] cipherText = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String plainEncodedText = decrypt(cipherText);
byte[] plainTextAsByte = Base64.decode(plainEncodedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
String plainTextAgain = new String(plainTextAsByte , "UTF-8");
```

Now print the `plainTextAgain` and hope this will work!

Comment: You're partly right, but there is something else going on, because the ciphertext is never Base64 decoded during decryption. Also, encoding "hola" should yield "aG9sYQ==..." not "holg...".

Comment: @ArtjomB. `decrypt(byte[] input)` method takes param `input` as byte array. So I'm assuming that the caller is responsible for proper decoding. I updated my answer. ty.

Comment: @rakeb.void with this changed when I trying to send "hi" I get in the other side "hg=="

Comment: @Juan. Hows your caller calls your `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` methods? Can you post your callers code?

Comment: This is an issue, but it is not *the* issue. You are correct in the sense that you should use `ctLength` to determine the output size during decryption. `getOutputSize()` only estimates the output size after decryption; from the JavaDoc: "The actual output length of the next `update` or `doFinal` call may be smaller than the length returned by this method."

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. Your input and output types of the decryption function are reversed. If you encrypt a `byte[]`, you should get one out when you decrypt it. If your ciphertext is a Base64 `String` then the decryption method should take such a `String` and not a `byte[]`.

   ```
   String encrypt(byte[] plaintext) {
       ...
       return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plaintext), Base64.DEFAULT);
   }

   byte[] encrypt(String ciphertext) {
       ...
       return cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(ciphertext.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
   }
   ```
2. You're passing a single plaintext and ciphertext into their respective method, but then use `cipher.update()` *and* `cipher.doFinal()`. This is not necessary. You should use a single `cipher.doFinal()` call without a previous buffer. Encryption example:

   ```
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
   byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
   ```
3. Since "Hola" is supposed to be what the user typed in, it doesn't make any sense to *decode* from Base 64. Not all strings that someone types in are valid Base 64 encoded so that they can be decoded. You shouldn't decode the input at all, but pass it directly into the `encrypt()` function.
4. Using `String#getBytes()` is unsafe, because it uses the default Charset of the system. The decryption might not succeed when a different default Charset is used on the receiving system. You should specify the Charset yourself and get the String from the `byte[]` after decryption:

   ```
   String ciphertext = encrypt(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
   String recoveredPlaintext = new String(decrypt(ciphertext), "UTF-8");
   ```
5. You're not using your static IV.

---

Security Issues:

1. You're using ECB mode. Don't do this! It's not semantically secure. Use at least CBC mode with a random IV. The IV doesn't have to be hidden, so you can simply prepend it to the ciphertext.
2. You're not authenticating the ciphertext. Your system might be vulnerable to the padding oracle attack. You should either use an encrypt-then-MAC approach with a strong MAC like HMAC-SHA256 or use an authenticated mode of operation for AES like GCM or EAX.

Use for example [this library](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto) by [Isaac Potoczny-Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2808114/isaac-potoczny-jones) of which is compatible with Android. It supports AES-CBC with a random IV and ciphertext authentication with HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: respect the point one the encrypt and decrypt are made as follow encrypt(Base64.decode(messageText.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)); and decrypt(Base64.decode(message.getBody(), Base64.DEFAULT));

Comment: If "Hola" is supposed to be the human readable string that you want to encrypt, then it doesn't make any sense to *decode* it from Base64, because it isn't. Not all human readable texts are valid Base64 encodings.

Comment: What is a readable human encoding, and how Can I change my code for achieve readable for humans?

Comment: As I understand it you want to encrypt text messages that somebody has written. Those should be the direct input to your encrypt() function and not a decoded version thereof.